# how to read a file line by line and each line as an argument input to a .exe file and capture the output to another file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to write a shell script that reads a .txt file line by line, and each line will as the input to my .exe file and I also want to capture the output of the .exe file and export it to another .txt file. my code likes that, but it doesn't work. when I try input manually like "./caculate.exe "1" the program also do not take 1 as an input, still ask me to input manually again.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
  ./caculate.exe "$LINE"
done < data.txt > f.txt
```

Comment: Do you really have all the code on the `#!/bin/bash` line? Or is that a copying error?

Comment: Does `calculate.exe` read from standard input? If it does, it will read from the `data.txt` file.

Comment: If `./calculate.exe "1"` doesn't work manually, why would you expect it to work in the script?

Comment: now I change the  part of the code to   echo ''$line" | ./caculate.exe, still not work

Comment: How do you use `calculate.exe` normally?

Comment: the calculate.exe give me user 3 option 1,2,0 if enter 1, the cal will require another 2 numbers to add them together if you enter 2, it requires another 2 numbers to do subtract, enter 0 will exit the program

Comment: Then you can't do it with a loop like this, since each iteration just gives it one line of input. Why don't you just do `./calculate.exe < data.txt`?

Comment: Welcome to the community! Could you please polish your code format a bit more so it could help the others? I could read it's a bash script but it has no line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If `calculate.exe` normally gets its input from standard input, you need to pipe the variable to it, not use an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line" | ./calculate.exe
done < data.txt > f.txt
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me an error   Syntax error: redirection unexpected,

Comment: How are you running the script? That would happen if you use `sh scriptname` instead of `bash scriptname` or `./scriptname`, since here-strings are a bash extension.

Comment: That's because you're only giving one line of input to the program, but you said it wants multiple inputs. I told you above that this approach can't work.

Comment: and now I found it, but the output gives me an infinity output and looks like it only executes the first line of the data.txt